# How to Use DataTrigger to set a property defined in the ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I am writing a XAML file which use DataTrigger to set a property in the ViewModel. The ViewModel class defined as:

```
public class ShellModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    public Brush ForegroundBrush
    {
        get; set;
    }

    ....................
}
```

I want to use DataTrigger in the View.xaml to set the property ForegroundBrush. The XAML I wrote is:

```
<StatusBar Name="statusBar" Grid.Row="3">
    <StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ForegroundBrush" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ForegroundBrush" Value="Black" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StatusBarItem.Style>
        <TextBlock Name="statusBarMessage" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundBrush}" Text="{Binding StatusMessage}"></TextBlock>
     </StatusBarItem>
     ........................
```

This does not compile. When I changed the

```
     <Setter Property="ForegroundBrush" Value="Black" />
```

to

```
     <Setter Property="ShellModel.ForegroundBrush" Value="Black" />
```

it gives me error:

> Dependency property field missing ....

How shall I write this so that the DataTrigger can set the property ForegroundBrush in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 9):

Setters in your DataTriggers should change properties of your UI elements only (and also they only work with DependencyProperties).
Set the `Foregound` Property of your StatusBarItem directly and set the TargetType of the Style. That should help.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBarItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasError}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Having information about the visual representation in your ViewModel is usually not a good idea anyway.